# detect if user has clicked on any of 6 div id elems

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 6 div ids, that I need to write an `if` condition to, to do something only if any of those *6* unique ids have been clicked on by the user.

I know I could do something like below, but I really don't want 6 of these functions one after another. Is there a better approach?

```
var el = document.getElementById('one');

el.onclick = function() {
    console.log('Click just happened');
};
```

Comment: Can you edit the HTML and add a class to each of them? If you can, you can get all of them into an array, and apply one function to all of them.

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to capture the click on the last 6 items <li>s in a long list. I do not want all items in the list.

Comment: Why not give a class to only the last 6 <li> items, and not every <li> item?

Answer (score 2):

This may work.

```js
const father = document.querySelector("#father")
const children = father.children;
[...children].forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.innerText)
    })
})
```

```html
<div id="father">
    <button>one</button>
    <button>two</button>
    <button>three</button>
    <button>four</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can change your HTML, you give all of your 6 elements a specific class. Then, getElementsByClassName returns the matched elements, and you can iterate through them to give them all the same event.

```
var elementsList = document.getElementsByClassName("class");

for (var i = 0; i < elementsList.length; i++) {
    elementsList[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log('Click just happened');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** **Select by IDs:**

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("parent")

Array.from(parent.children).forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(`${e.target.innerText} clicked`)
  })
})
```

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
}

#id1,
#id2,
#id3,
#id4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1px
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="id1">1</div>
  <div id="id2">2</div>
  <div id="id3">3</div>
  <div id="id4">4</div>
</div>
```

---

**Select by classes**

```js
const el = document.querySelectorAll('.classname').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    console.log(`${e.target.innerText} clicked`)

  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.classname {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="classname">1</div>
  <div class="classname">2</div>
  <div class="classname">3</div>
  <div class="classname">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even if you cannot add class to the elements you can use their `id`s. Something like this. `document.querySelectorAll('#one,#two,#three,#four')...`

Comment: Indeed, I edited to select the IDs with same logic though.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is more appropriate to use `classes` or `data-attributes` for such mission/idea (Over time it's very **easy** to `break` code that relies on specific list of id names matches to specific list of HTML elements  + Tidy to manage).

Anyway, very basic/simple starter for list of #id:

```js
var list = [
  'one',
  'two',
  'three',
  'four',
  'five',
  'six'
];

list.forEach(function (idElement, index) {
  el = document.getElementById(idElement);
  el.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Click on id:" + idElement + " just happened");
  };
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="one">one</li>
  <li id="two">two</li>
  <li id="three">three</li>
  <li id="four">four</li>
  <li id="five">five</li>
  <li id="six">six</li>
  <li id="another-element">another-element</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use ***CLASS***, u can use this function and just add the **class name** to all the divs that you want.

```
 (function () {
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div-class');
    divs.forEach(div => div.onclick = _ => console.log('hello'));
})()
```

If you use ***ID***, u have to add the ***ID*** of the div in the following ***array***.

```
(function () {
    const divs = ['id-1', 'id-2', 'id-3'];
    divs.forEach(div =>document.querySelector(`#${div}`).onclick = _ => console.log('hello'));
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// if this one event for 6 div elements you can do this.
 function fN() {
      let na = ['.one','.two','.three'];
      for (let i = 0; i < na.length; i++) {
           let xr = document.querySelector(na[i]);
            xr.style.display = 'none';
           console.log(xr);
      }
 }
 fN();
```